# Add entry for a logfile

Tags: scripting, logs

How can I add a logfile line to the following bash file?

```
#!/bin/sh

if ps x |grep -v grep |grep -c cccam_2.3.2 >/dev/null
then
    echo "cccam... ok"
else
    echo "cccam... restarting"
    /var/bin/cccam_2.3.2 &
fi
```

Comment: What do you mean by `add a logfile line`? Do you want to send the `echo` stuff to your logfile instead to stdout?

Comment: I mean:see a log file e.g in tmp or else only" if the program has been restarted"

Comment: Sorry, still did not get what you actually want to achieve. Do you just want to create an empty file in `/tmp`? Or do you want to put some information there?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want to use `logger` command like here:

```
root@dst:~# logger "Hello log stuff."
root@dst:~# grep Hello /var/log/messages 
Jan 27 16:32:42 dst root: Hello log stuff.
```

`man logger` provides nice options too.

Comment: @Thomas.Should be a file in tmp with only the date and time when the process was restarted

Comment: @ddinc `logger` uses the standard logging facility - an excellent suggestion given you only said you wanted a log line, and didn't specify it had to be a suboptimal home-grown solution.

Comment: sorry for causing misunderstanding.but I still don't know how to put a logger command everytime ""echo "cccam... restarting""" occurs.

Comment: add line: logger "cccam... restarting"

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also add -x with shell script and redirect that to a logfile. I use it to log and debug few shell scripts

Something like this

```
sh -x your_script.sh 2> logfile.log
```

Comment: don't know if I got it right but both suggestions produce no logs    #!/bin/sh

if ps x |grep -v grep |grep -c cccam_2.3.2 >/dev/null
then
echo "cccam... ok"
else
echo "cccam... restarting"
/var/bin/cccam_2.3.2 &
sh -x cccam.sh 2> logfile.log
fi

Comment: @ddinc what do you see if you run the sh -x your_script.sh 2> logfile.log outside the script.

This should create a log of the shell script while its running into the logfile you mention in the same location.

Comment: get this:root@dm820:/var/bin# sh -x cccam.sh 2> logfile.log
cccam... ok
root@dm820:/var/bin# cccam.sh
cccam... ok
root@dm820:/var/bin#     no log though

Comment: `[root@localhost ~]# sh -x shell.sh 2> log
cccam... restarting
[root@localhost ~]# cat log
+ grep -v grep
+ ps x
+ grep -c cccam_2.3.2
+ echo 'cccam... restarting'
+ /var/bin/cccam_2.3.2
shell.sh: line 8: /var/bin/cccam_2.3.2: No such file or directory`
I did a small test on one my VM using your code and see a log like this. I didnt had the right files so i got error. Is this close to what you need ?